# How .php?id= and ?id= RewriteRule in .htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I edited the code as follows and worked but now I have a problem.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.newdomain.com/about? [L,R=301]
```

My pages worked with `www.oldsite.com/index.php?id=` format.

Now I need this structure: `www.oldsite.com/?id=`

Example for single page: `?id=1`
Example for batch pages: `?id=1`, `?id=2`, ..

If you give examples for both, love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it to work on `/?id=` as well as `/index.php?id=` you can make the URl-path optional. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ https://www.newdomain.com/about? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: `?` is special character in regex as well